# gotoAndPlay() jumps to Frame 2 instead of Frame 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am really confused about this issue ...

In the first Frame i wrote the following code:

```
stop();
var currentInterInfo:IntersectionInfo = null;
var currentInter:Intersection;
gotoAndPlay("Frame3");
```

and in the 2nd frame (labeled "Frame2") i wrote:

```
stop();
trace("Frame2");
```

and in the 3rd frame (labeled "Frame3") i wrote:

```
stop();
currentInter = new Intersection(.....); // notes that the constructor of the Intersection class is empty
trace("Frame3");
```

When I run it, i get "Frame 2" in the output although i should get "Frame 3" as a result ...
and When I debug, i get "Frame 3" ...
no idea whats wrong here ...
I uploaded my project in the link below in case u want to check it out ...

[BugReproduce.rar](http://www.mediafire.com/file/s7hdlcmiai4kum7/BugReproduce.rar)

Comment: Can you please localize the problem? Cut off all the transitions and effects, remove the code statement by statement - will the problem persist? There's much code in your project, besides the version of FLA is incompatible with my Flash CS.

Comment: Well, I tried to localize the problem more than that but i couldn't ... if i tried to remove more code/functions from the Intersection class the problem disappear and it will function correctly (weird huh =/, although i am not using any of these functions) ...

Comment: forget to tell that if u commented/removed 
        [currentInter = new Intersection(.....);]
the problem will disappear as well ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me!.

The case in this sutuation is:

When you compiling the SWF inside the flash or loading it, it is loading all of the frames.

So at this point not all of the frames are stacked, so you are beeing sent to the last one available in this case it is 2.

in the 1st frame change your code to:

```
import flash.utils.setTimeout;
stop();

var currentInterInfo:IntersectionInfo = null;
var currentInter:Intersection;

setTimeout ( init, 100 )

function init ()
{
    gotoAndPlay("Frame3");
}
```

Or somehow prevent application launch before it is completely loaded.

Comment: thnx, i will try that as soon as i get home ..... hope it works ...
just one thing, shouldnt the flash compiler checks if the last frame in the stack is labeled "Frame3", if not it fires an exception instead of loading the incorrect frame ?

Comment: I was always under the impression that no code will run until the swf is completely loaded. After all we are talking about compiled code.

Comment: it works, thnx .... will i need to increase the delay (100) if i had more frames to stack ?

Comment: i think you will not be needing to increase delay.